# How can I fix the error 'unable to open configuration settings file' when deploying an Ionic 5 hybrid mobile app on iOS with Cocoapods?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoapods, hybrid-mobile-app, ionic5

I have been trying to deploy an angular ionic but I have been experiencing the error below:

```
Issue file:///Volumes/workspace/repository/ios/App/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-App/Pods-App.release.xcconfig
unable to open configuration settings file (1)
```

I tried deleting the pod file and reinstalled Cocoapod but nothing has changed. I deleted the project and re-initiated the project with npm build and generated an instance of the app

Comment: hey did you find any resolution to this?

Comment: None yet brother.